# UdpClient receiving and sending at the same time

Tags: .net, multithreading, udpclient

I am maintaining other's code and its using the class `UdpClient`. The code declares one instance of `UdpClient` and receives data continuously using the `UdpClient.Receive()`.

When data is received, it is processed in another thread and the `UdpClient` calls `Receive()` again. At the same time when the data is processed the same client is sending a response back.

Question: Is this a bug? I think so because `UdpClient` is not thread safe so you can not call two methods at the same time. Anyways code is working fine but ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that something isn't thread-safe doesn't mean you can't call two methods via different threads (or even one method via different threads), it just means that when the class was designed it wasn't designed with thread-safety at mind, thus the results of concurrent access are "unpredictable" from your POV.

This is not a bug. This is a mis-use.

Comment: So that means that maybe everything works by luck or maybe everything works because the Receive and Send methods does not interfere each other, rigth?

Comment: Ok, I'm going to fix this mis-use. I don-not want to rely on God. Thanks :)